# How to use putSQL in apache nifi

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, data-warehouse

I a beginner in data `warehousing` and `apache nifi`. I was trying taking the Mysql table data into nifi and then want to put that data into another mysql database table, I am successfully getting data from the database table one and I can also able to print that data into file using `putFile` processor.

But now I want to store that queued data into mysql database table, I know there is `putSQL` processor but it was not working for me.
Can anyone let me know how to do it correctly.

Here are the screenshots of my flow

[image]

PutSQL configuration-
[image]

[image]

[image]

I converted data from Avro to JSON and then JSON to SQL in case if that would work, but this also not worked.

Comment: Not working is very vague statement, are you getting any error while executing `PutSQL` or data is not loaded properly?

Comment: I am not getting data saved in the database using putSQL.

Comment: Can you share the configuration for PutSQL?

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde I have added the screen shots .

Answer (score 0):

Use `PutDatabaseRecord` and remove the `Convert*` processors.

From nifi docs:

> The PutDatabaseRecord processor uses a specified RecordReader to input
> (possibly multiple) records from an incoming flow file. These records
> are translated to SQL statements and executed as a single transaction.
> If any errors occur, the flow file is routed to failure or retry, and
> if the records are transmitted successfully, the incoming flow file is
> routed to success. The type of statement executed by the processor is
> specified via the Statement Type property, which accepts some
> hard-coded values such as INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE, as well as 'Use
> statement.type Attribute', which causes the processor to get the
> statement type from a flow file attribute. IMPORTANT: If the Statement
> Type is UPDATE, then the incoming records must not alter the value(s)
> of the primary keys (or user-specified Update Keys). If such records
> are encountered, the UPDATE statement issued to the database may do
> nothing (if no existing records with the new primary key values are
> found), or could inadvertently corrupt the existing data (by changing
> records for which the new values of the primary keys exist).

This should be more performant and cleaner.

Comment: so basically I can connect the data flow from QueryDatabaseTableRecord to PutDatabaseRecord ?

Comment: @Amara. Yes. Of course the schemas should match.